# Error PDO insert: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I'm trying to insert with PDO id_facebook (mysql bigint), name(mysql varchar) and email(mysql varchar), but can not resolve this error, the PDO syntax looks correct, what can be?

```
public static function inserirUsuarioFacebook($id_facebook, $nome, $email)
{
    try
    {
        $pdo = Conexao::getInstance();

        $consulta = $pdo->prepare("INSERTO INTO usuario_facebook (id_facebook, nome, email) VALUES (:id_facebook, ':nome', ':email')");
        $consulta->bindParam(':id_facebook', $id_facebook, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $consulta->bindParam(':nome', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $consulta->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $consulta->execute();   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: ops, I had not seen, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't quote placeholders. That turns them into strings, not placeholders:

```
... VALUES(:id_facebook, :nome, :email)
                         ^----^-^-----^--- note the lack of quotes
```

is all that's required

The whole point of placeholders is to remove any need for quoting/escaping. The DB engine takes care of all that for you.